# Between or Among

Tags: prepositions, between-among

Sentence

> A feasibility survey has now
>   been completed in India to establish
>   a network to felicitate contacts
>   **between small and medium enterprises**.

What is the right form?

> Between small and medium enterprises.

or

> Among small and medium enterprises.

Comment: What's the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Agreed. More context is required. A *very basic rule* is we use *between* when we are talking about two things/people and *among* for more than two. *It's between you and me.; It's among us.*

Comment: @ Maulik.. Here we are talking about two different types of things which are enterprises..But there may be a lot of small or medium enterprises more than two..Then what to use between or among??Should I use 'between' considering the two types of enterprise or 'among' considering the number of enterprise?

Comment: You are talking about the segment and thus you may possibly consider *small enterprises* - A group; *medium enterprises* - B group. So, there are two groups. This said, *between*. *"Between small and medium enterprises, we should target the latter one; there's huge potential."* **But** *"Among small enterprises, 'X' is leading the market."*

Comment: @TzD: You know what you want to say, how can _we_ answer which one it is? Use _between_ if you are talking about small enterprises and medium enterprises, and use _among_ is you mean _small and medium enterprises_ (usually, people use that expression to mean **one** group of enterprises!).

Comment: As such, if you mean small enterprises and medium enterprises, I _would_ suggest you name them as such. The expression you use now will generally not be understood as referring to two separate groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference in meaning, so the “right” form depends on what you want to say.

**Between** indicate that something happens involving (at least) two specific (types) of entities.

> A feasibility survey has now been completed in India to establish a network to felicitate contacts **between** small and medium enterprises.

This sentence means that contacts are facilitated between **small enterprises** and **medium enterprises**.

While it is possible that this is the intended meaning, I doubt it. It would make sense if one would wrote something like:

> We are trying to facilitate better contacts between citizens and the government.

Usually, the expression *small and medium enterprises* is used to refer to all those enterprises that are not considered “big”. So we are talking about *one* group of enterprises.

**Among** is used to indicate interaction between members of *one* specific group<sup>(*)</sup>. So it is very likely that the actually intended meaning of the sentence is indeed:

> A feasibility survey has now been completed in India to establish a network to felicitate contacts **among** small and medium enterprises.

This would mean that enterprises in the groups of *small and medium enterprises* form contacts with other enterprises in the same group. To my mind, this makes more sense than the version with *between*.

Another simple example of this use, to contrast it with the contacts between citizens and the government:

> We also try to facilitate contacts among citizens.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> It can also mean the existence of something within a group, but that meaning doesn't seem relevant here: *I wanted to find the strongest men among the athletes*.