# In this context, can I use among?

Tags: prepositions, between-among

> The territorial dispute over South China Sea ***among*** China and its neighbors is being intensified with an increase in both a potential value of natural resources in the region and a strategic value of sea lines of communication.

The reason that I put among instead of "between" is to avoid ambiguity.
For example, if i say "between," I thought the sentence means "China versus other neighbors allied".

I wanted to mean "China versus country A versus B versus C.. ."
So, the question is, my usage is correct? If not, how can I edit this?

Comment: I really don't get why "between" was replaced.

Comment: @VarunKN I mentioned the reason above. Or, did you mean that it is better to say "between" instead of "among"?

Comment: **Between** does not mean "between two objects", it can be used in relation to several objects. Related question: **[between vs. among](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31893/between-or-among)**

Comment: @Yunhee, Your reason isn't valid. 'Between' can be used. There isn't any ambiguity. 'Between' needn't imply 'China vs all the neighbors'. It can also mean 'China vs Neighbor 1 vs Neighbor 2 vs...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Among** signifies interaction within a given group, synonymous with **within**

> **Among** the boys, William was the tallest.

**Between** is used to show comparison

> **Between** William and David, William was taller.

If you mean the countries in that area, you could use

> The conflict **among** the South China Sea countries

Because you have specifically named **China** as one of the countries, it seems more natural to use **between**

> The conflict **between** China and its neighbors on the South China Sea

If you list several of the countries

> The conflict **between** China, Japan, Taiwan, and Korea
>   The conflict **among** China, Japan, Taiwan, and Korea

have the same meaning, however there is an ambiguity since it sounds like all the countries may be fighting with each other, not just one side versus another side

In your particular example, I believe the disputes are **between** China and the other countries. Although the other countries may not have a **formal alliance**, there may be some agreement **among** them as to a potential threat.