# Why does it use 'among', not 'between'?

Tags: prepositions

> To eavesdrop means you secretly listen to the conversations of others. Some types of people are very good at eavesdropping. Nosy people, people who like to gossip and spies are all good eavesdroppers. The only difference **among** my examples is that spies get paid and could get killed for getting an earful.

Why does it use 'among', not 'between' when there only be two items (nosy people and spies)?

Comment: This answer on ELU may be helpful (or it may be more than you ever wanted to know about among and between ;) ) : https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37636/

Comment: There are 3 items in your example.

Comment: A couple of related questions:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/77147/     https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26541/

Answer (score 2):

You can use either, but *among* is generally used to refer to more than two items or persons. Examples of standard practice:

> We shared the prize money among the five contestants.
>
> There are more differences between a banana and a plantain than many people realize.

You will still find many people who use *between* with more than two participants.

Comment: But there only be two items(nosy people and spies)

Comment: What about people who like to gossip? You listed those as well. That makes three. But regardless, the answer I gave gives you some good information.

Comment: Idiomatically, you'll hear variations of the usage, but grammatically speaking, "between" is always for two things and "among" for three or more.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie A usage note about "between and among" in MW [There is a persistent but unfounded notion that ‘between’ can be used only of two items and that ‘among’ must be used for more than two. ‘Between’ has been used of more than two since Old English; it is especially appropriate to denote a one-to-one relationship, regardless of the number of items.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between)

Comment: @ColleenV: That the notion is persistent has some probative value here for learners, since they are likely to encounter the less liberal view with this and other usages on standardized tests and from various institutions that subscribe, unthinkingly, to more prescriptive rules. For example, you wouldn't tell one of these people to go and use *singular they* or to end sentences with a preposition on a college application because the system may be unlikely to accept such usages even though they are linguistically fine.

Comment: @Robusto  I agree that it's important to encourage learners to understand what institutions are likely to view as correct. I think saying  *"between" is always for two things* doesn't fall into that category though. Between is about a 1:1 relationship. When we try to change that into only two "things" it gets confusing. For example: [between small and medium enterprises](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31893/). There are many "enterprises" there so why aren't we using 'among'? Native speakers understand that is a 1:1 relationship, but learners see the plural and get confused.