# How can I write a relationship among the objects in a sentence?

Tags: american-english, between-among

For instance, let’s say that I want to establish an association among 3 objects. In this case, let the objects be “Roses”, “Violets”, and ”Tulips”.

Then, if I want to say, for example, that in my garden there was an anthill among those three categories of flowers, how should I write it?

• There was an anthill among my roses, violets, and tulips.

or

• There was an anthill between my roses, violets, and tulips.

Another example could be:

• Here, I will explain the difference between roses, violets, and tulips.

or

• Here, I will explain the difference among roses, violets, and tulips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Between or Among](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31893/between-or-among)

Comment: I just flagged this, because that makes it easier for other people searching similar topics on the internet. The context of your question may be a bit different, but it's related to the difference between the two words. So, I thought that would be a good idea to connect similar posts and that might help someone in the future.

Comment: It woud be a bit quirky to use ***between*** with ***three*** referents, because etymologically (and *still*, semantically) ***between*** expresses a location relative to ***two*** positions (compare ***twin, twain***). So *There was an anthill between my violets and tulips* is perfectly natural. It would normally be understood to mean the anthill is on some imaginary line running from one place (where the violets are) to somewhere else (where the tulips are). But if you have ***three*** areas, it's not exactly clear how anything can be "between" them...

Comment: ...I can only really understand it as meaning the roses, violets, and tulips are all mixed up together anyway, and the anthill is somewhere in the middle of the "mixed" planting area. But it's not a good usage, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers quirky if it is being used to refer to a position in space, for sure, but the second part of the Q asks about *the difference between roses, violets and tulips*. In that case it is quite natural to have more than two elements. As for *among*, now that I think about it it doesn't seem to refer to an exact location - *somewhere among the roses, violets and tulips there was an anthill* is fine for me, as is *there were anthills among my roses, violets and tulips*, but I don't like *there was an anthill among my roses, violets and tullips*...

Comment: ... and yet *in the midst off* is fine there, even though it doesn't refer to a precise location either. *In amongst the roses, violets and tulips there was an anthill* also works IMO. I don't know why that should be different from *amongst*.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with "Switzerland is between Germany, France, Italy, and Austria". The two-ness of the etymology is irrelevant.

Comment: @Minty: I think your example is at least *slightly* "disingenuous". Strictly speaking there can't really be ***a single difference*** between three referents - so even though we'd often use the singular form there, what we really *mean* is *the **differences** [between more than two things]*. A single difference couldn't distinguish between three or more things, in most contexts.

Comment: ...okay, I know we can say things like ***The difference** between wrens, blackbirds, and vultures **is** primarily **one** of size - to a first approximation they're all birds*

Comment: @ColinFine me neither... and yet *there was an anthill between my roses, violets, and tulips* doesn't work AFAIC. I think the problem must be that if you say *my roses, violets and tulips*, it sounds as though you are talking about one flowerbed, as FF says in the fourth post down - if so the solution is to say *there was an anthill between the roses, the violets and the tulips*, which sounds fine to me. Similarly I prefer *there was an anthill between the roses and THE tulips*.

Comment: @Minty I have no problem with *an anthill between my roses, violets, and tulips*. This is not different in any way than the earlier Switzerland example. If you see it as being different, then you are constructing some kind of different geography in your head for it that makes it different.

Comment: @JasonBassford The difference is that Germany, France, Italy and Austria are four distinct areas, whereas I would normally read *my roses, violets and tulips* in the way FumbleFingers seems to be reading it, or in other words as referring to a single flowerbed planted with a mixture of roses, violets and tulips - so yes, the geography is different, if you want to put it that way.

Comment: The trouble is that *between* requires more than referent, so it's fine in the Switzerland example but is at least questionable in the example with the flowers, unless you rephrase it to refer to three distinct areas, e.g. by saying *the roses, the violets...*. Then it is the same as the example with the countries.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that either

> There was an anthill among my roses, violets, and tulips.

or

> There was an anthill between my roses, violets, and tulips.

could be acceptable. If there were three separate groups of flowers, say in a triangular arrangement, and the anthill is in the middle, I would use "between". If they were all mixed, I would use "among". I note that in heraldry, to express the concept that one object is within a goup of other objects, the only correct verb is "between" *A bend between five bezants*. (A diagonal line with three coins above it and two below.)

I would say

> Here, I will explain the difference**s** between roses, violets, and tulips.

I might also use a version with "among" but I would be less inclined to do so.