# among us vs between us

Tags: prepositions

I know that "between" is used when the individual items are specified and "among" is used when they are not. Ref:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/between-among/ . Examples:

- I need to choose between Yale, Oxford and Stanford.
- I need to choose among these universities.

Based on that, "among us" should be correct and "between us" incorrect, but I am not sure this is always valid. For instance:

- Let's keep it between us.
- Let's keep it among us.

Both sound correct to me. Is that right? If so, is it an exception or have I misunderstood the rule used to choose between "between" and "among" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Between or Among](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31893/between-or-among)

Comment: @EllieK No, that answer leads me to belive that "among us" is the only correct choice because "us" is one specific group, not specific entities of the group.

Comment: *I need to choose among these universities,* is not something one would read/hear without supporting context.  You and your listener would know the universities.  In which case you would be saying the same thing as your sentence listing the universities.  Your example is flawed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Between them vs Among them](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266393/between-them-vs-among-them)

Comment: Related question on our sister site EL&U: [“between” vs. “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37636/80039)

Answer (score 0):

*Between* strongly implies *either/or*.

> I need to choose between Yale, Oxford, and Stanford (you need to choose exactly one of either Yale, or Oxford, or Stanford).

*Between* also might be used to imply that you're giving up something by choosing something else.

*Among X* is simply saying what your pool of choices are.  It can be used in something less rigid than *either/or*, but is OK to use in a strict *either/or* situation as well.

> I need to choose among the chocolate, coconut, or caramel ice cream flavors (You can choose more than one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it focuses only on my initial examples and does not deal with my main question (keep it between us / keep it among us).

Answer (score 0):

> **Between** can be used when you have distinct individual choices(options) which is usually about 2/3 choices where
>   **Among** can be used when you have (the number of groups containing) choices(options) more than 3.

For eg.

> I have to choose **between** Berklee or Yale.
>
> The decision of choosing an appropriate university **among** the given
>   list was literally difficult.

Comment: When you're a group of friends having some secret about your professor at that time you can tell in the group that Let's keep it among us.
While with your single friend you can tell him/her that Let's keep it between us.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose '**between**' if with regards to the matter at hand, a one-to-one correspondence through the objects is the intended framing.
2. Choose '**among**' if with regards to the matter at hand, a one-to-one correspondence through the objects is not the intended framing.

Examples:

- I shall choose **between** Yale, Oxford and Stanford.

  I shall choose **among** the Ivy League universities.
- There's evil **among** Peter and John.

  There's evil **among** the villagers.
- We kept it **between**/**among** the three of us.

  The townsfolk kept it **among**/**between** themselves.

  (Here, choosing 'among' over 'between' would emphasise the non-structuredness of the internal interactions, as well as the collectiveness, of the group.)

Answer (score -1):

"Let's keep it between us / among us."

This is not idiomatic. This is preposterous  to the natives.
Usual grammatical rule is not applicable here.

Instead, one should say :

Let's keep it between you and me.

Let's keep it between you and us.

Let's keep it between ourselves.

[ BETWEEN OURSELVES : (AmE.) =  'between you and me', 
meaning : 'in confidence', 'as a secret'. 
Source : Collins Dictionary ]

Comment: "Let's keep it among us" is not idiomatic. Some native speakers might mistakenly say it when they are over-correcting themselves (like inappropriately using "I" instead of "me"), but "Just between {us/you and me/you and me and the bedpost/etc}." is an idiom and the regular "rules" of among and between don't apply.

Comment: @ColleenV, thank you for your valuable opinion.

Comment: For a shared secret (for example) we would always say ‘between us’, perhaps because we are joined by a shared secret rather than the secret being an entity in itself that is part of a group.